# What does "rc=$$? ; cat File1 >/proc/self/fd/2 ; exit $$rc" comand do in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash

Please help me understand the following command completely:

```
python3 code.py >result.txt 2>&1 || ( rc=$$? ; cat result.txt >/proc/self/fd/2 ; exit $$rc )
```

In the above code, I couldn't find out what `rc=$$?` and `$$rc` mean.

Comment: Is this from a Makefile or something?

Comment: @Shawn its a linux shell command

Comment: Looks like it's wrapped in something else that evaluates the string before the shell (Turning `$$` into `$` as it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash `$$` is the process ID and `?` is used to find the return value of the last executed command. So basically this fetches process ID and assign it a variable `rc`. Then it looks like exit with code equals to process ID.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

please explain the part with "$$rc" once again.

Comment: Exit command is finishing the scenario and it accepts an integer argunent that is exit code. Here it exits with code stored in `$$rc` and this is a process ID. So, for some reasons this store PID to variable `rc`, runs the `cat` command and finishes this with returning PID as exit code.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. I got it. :)

Comment: @Charnel: I beg to differ with your opinion; but maybe I made a mistake in my line of thinking. My I ask you to have a look at my answer, which gives a different explanation, and point out if you find some error in it?

Comment: I think this is from some Makefile. You are right to a part that `$?` is the exit status of the last executed command. In Makefile as well, the variables are dereferenced with `$variable`. If within a Makefile, you want to treat a variable as shell variable, escape the `$` as `$$`, So, a Makefile statement - `echo $$var` translates to `echo $var` when seen by the shell. The line does not exit with the code == PID.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the code does not make much sense. If you try by yourself on the command line the following:

```
false; rc=$$?; echo $rc; echo $$rc
```

you will see that the first echo outputs some number, followed by a question mark, and the second number outputs the same number, followed by the letters `rc`.

The reason is that `$$` is a special variable maintained by bash, which holds the current process id. While there is also a variable which holds the exit code of the most recently executed command, it is named `$?`, but never referenced in the code you posted. Hence, the shell will, in general, assign to the variable `rc` a string containing the PID, and simply add the subsequent `?` to it.

I said *in general*, because there is an exception, just it is highly unlikely to occur. The reason is that `?` is also a valid wildcard pattern in globbing, and matches any character. Now let's assume that the PID of your shell is `4711`, and in the current working directory happens to be a file with name `4711x`. The `$$?` would be `4711?`, the `?` would match the `x`, and `rc` would end up with the name `4711x` instead of `4711?`. The result would be even funnier, if you had two similar files, `4711x` and `4711y`. Try it!

The `exit $$rc` is even more bizarre. As explained before, `$$rc` expands to something like `4711rc`, and `exit 4711rc` is simply illegal; you would get an error message *bash: exit: ...: numeric argument required*

From this, I think that either whoever wrote this code, never debugged it, or you made some mistake when copying and pasting it into this question.

Comment: I suspect @Shawn's comment is on the right track; in a makefile, `$$` is an escaped dollar-sign, so `rc=$$?` in a makefile would translate to the shell command `rc=$?`, which would get the exit code of the last command and store it in the variable `rc`. Similarly, `exit $$rc` translates to `exit $?`, which (since this is in a subshell) would effectively reset the exit code back to what it was earlier.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP did not confirm Shawns question that this is a makefile, and explicitly answered in his comment that this would be a normal bash command. Also, the question is not tagged as `makefile`.